# How to rotate a 3D character on top of a plane with an isometric picture on it

Tags: unity, isometric, angles

How to calculate the angles of the 3d charater so that it fits into the isometric environment projektet on a 2d plane?
Also, how do you calculate the rotation of my character?
What I want to achieve:
[image: image 1]
Describing the scenario:
[image: image 2]
[image: image3]

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably want to switch your camera to orthographic, so that you don't get perspective distortion in the image. Then I wouldn't put the image on the ground like that, but rather a plane perpendicular to and linked to the camera. Then rather than rotating the player around, I'd be orienting the camera so that the player looks correct.

The exact position and rotation of the camera is specific to your isometric image, but it looks something like 45 degrees to the right and 45 degrees down.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your camera, like the other fellows said, is probably the best, but if you still need the Camera to have *perspective* projection, you can use `LookAt()`, like this:

```
3dGameObject.transform.LookAt(camera.transform);
```

Basically it makes your game object to rotate in order to **look** at something. Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) for more information on which side of the object (forward) will be looking at the camera and how to specify your "up" coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Unity3D to use isometric rendering in the camera settings.

Secondly, you dont use isometrical graphics on a plane, you just build the world in 2D/3D and let the camera make it isometric.

I know this isnt a direct answer about rotation, but if you use my approach, your problem is solved. :-)

I quickly did a Google search on the topic and found this tutorial on YouTube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqIMbWKeXCA

I also got some articles/tutorials on it, I think this one could be of usage for you too:
http://indiehoodgames.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/tip-designing-a-isometric-game-in-unity3d/

Remember, most of the time, someone else has had the exact same problem as you, so Google first. :-)